# Zend: Principle of Adding TSRMLS_XX?

Tags: php, php-extension

I'm currently working on a PHP extension and maybe like many other newbies to extensions, I'm really confused about the `tsrm_ls`.

I've read the article of http://blog.golemon.com/2006/06/what-heck-is-tsrmlscc-anyway.html so that I basically know the goal of `TSRM` and how it works now. But I'm still wondering where on earth to put the macros. The article says that the compiler may notice you for the lack of `tsrm_ls` but I've tried deleting some `TSRMLS_XX`es in my code and it actually compiled smoothly.

I've googled a lot for examples of functions when coding but I'm still concerned about it now (although ZTS is disabled in most production environments). So here're two questions:

1. Is there a principle of adding `TSRMLS_XX`?
2. Is there a way to test for the lack of `TSRMLS_XX`?

Comment: Do you define, or need to use any provided, re-entrant methods?  If not, then you can blithely remove all thread local storage references.

Comment: @bishop I've wrapped some custom classes in my project so that I'm using numbers of APIs of the object storage. I know that the global variable is a sensitive part of TSRM after reading the article, then what about the objects?